# Outputting to a text file in Java

Tags: java, file

This is a homework assignment, I have to write a program that reads a "input.txt" file and sees how many times to print a salutation (ex: Donald Duck, 4 so it prints Hello Donald Duck four times) 
The problem I'm having is with outputting the salutation into a text file called "output.txt" 
For some reason it only prints out the salutation for the last line in the input.txt instead of all of them.. Here's what I have so far:

```
   import java.util.*;
   import java.io.*;

   public class Driver0 {

      public static void main (String [] args) {
         Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Would you like the output to be written to a file?");
         Scanner read;
         String input = userInput.nextLine(); //user input
         if(input.equals("yes")) {
            System.out.println("Writing to \"output.txt\" now..");
         }
         else {
            System.out.println("Printing to screen:"); 
         }        
            try {
            read = new Scanner(new File("input.txt")); //scanner reading file
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e){
               System.out.println("File not found.");
               return;
            }
         while(read.hasNextLine()) {
            String newInput = read.nextLine();
            String [] inputArray = newInput.split(","); //spliting
            int num = 0;
            num = Integer.parseInt(inputArray[2].trim());
                for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                if(input.equals("yes")) {  //writing to file 
                    Driver0.outputting(inputArray);
                  }
               else { //writing to screen
                  System.out.println("Hello" + inputArray[1] + inputArray[0]); 
               }
            } 
         }
      }
      public static void outputting (String [] inputArray) {
         PrintWriter output = null;
         String fileName = "output.txt";
            try {
            output = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileName)); 
            } 
            catch(IOException error){
               System.out.println("Sorry, can't open for writing.");
               return;
            }
            output.println("Hello" + inputArray[1] + inputArray[0]);
                output.close();       
      } 
   }
```

My problem is most likely within the outputting method or where it has a comment that says writing to file next to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FileWriter` class has a [second constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29) that takes a `boolean` argument to tell it to append to the end of the existing file rather than overwrite it from the start.

```
output = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileName, true));
```

Comment: Thank you!! This totally worked you're awesome :)

Answer (score 4):

Every time through the `while` loop you're creating a new [`PrintWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#print%28java.lang.String%29), writing one line to it, then closing it.  This is just overwriting the file each time.   You probably should only create one `PrintWriter` that you keep open and *append* to it instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are creating each time a new file Using a new PrintWriter.

a minimally changed ,Quick fix for your sulution, will be (**although there are yet many design problems in your code**):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Driver0 {

  public static void main (String [] args) {
     Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Would you like the output to be written to a file?");
     Scanner read;
     String input = userInput.nextLine(); //user input
     if(input.equals("yes")) {
        System.out.println("Writing to \"output.txt\" now..");
     }
     else {
        System.out.println("Printing to screen:"); 
     }        
        try {
        read = new Scanner(new File("input.txt")); //scanner reading file
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e){
           System.out.println("File not found.");
           return;
        }
        ////////////////////////
        PrintWriter output;
        String fileName = "output.txt";
        try {
        output = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileName)); 
        } 
        catch(IOException error){
           System.out.println("Sorry, can't open for writing.");
           return;
        }
        ////////////////////////
     while(read.hasNextLine()) {
        String newInput = read.nextLine();
        String [] inputArray = newInput.split(","); //spliting
        int num = 0;
        num = Integer.parseInt(inputArray[2].trim());
            for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            if(input.equals("yes")) {  //writing to file 
                Driver0.outputting(output,inputArray);
              }
           else { //writing to screen
              System.out.println("Hello" + inputArray[1] + inputArray[0]); 
           }
        } 
     }
     ///////////////////////////////
     output.close();       
     ///////////////////////////////
  }
  public static void outputting (PrintWriter output,String [] inputArray) {
        output.println("Hello" + inputArray[1] + inputArray[0]);
  } 
}
```